# Spring controller returns double slashes url

Tags: spring, url, controller

Spring controller is creating double slashes in URL, why?

For example the controller below will create a URL that looks like:
"http://localhost/myapp//customer_home" or, if login failed,
"http://localhost/myapp//login"

I am using **spring mvc 5.3.16**
Configuration classes is tagged below, hello world level minimal.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @ModelAttribute("login")
    public Login setLogin() {
        return new Login();
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Login login) {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("login") final Login login, final Model model) {
        
        // check login
        
        if (loginOK) {
            return  "redirect:customer_home"; 
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Login failed");
            return "login";
        }
    }

public class SpringDispatcherConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}

public class SpringDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    static {
        HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        new SocketServer().start();
    }

    @Override
    protected Class <?> [] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {
            SpringDispatcherConfig.class
        };
    }
    
    @Override  
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {  
        return null;
    }  

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {
            "/"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What is you context path? How it is configured?

Comment: I have added the config classes, copied from hello world tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

remove the slash from the context path in application.property (myapp).

Comment: There is no application.property file in the project. Is there some defaults that I need to overwrite with one?

Comment: application.property auto generated when u create a springBoot starter. It contains the supplements configuration of the application.